# Could not download org.springframework.vault

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle

I am importing the gradle project in eclipse which is the spring boot application. I could see all the dependency jars are downloaded except "org.springframework.vault".

I could download the spring-vault-core-2.0.1.RELEASE.pom file from browser, so no network issues i guess.

When i checked in D:\softwares\gradle-4.6-bin\gradle-4.6\caches\modules-2\files-2.1 i could not find this directory. I tried to create this directory but i got the error pop up says "folder/file in it is open in other program". I have restarted the pc, also killed all the java process and tried to create this dir, but still failed.

I deleted the cache directory itself and did gradle build, it downloaded the jars freshly except the mentioned one.

code cannot be shared as it is working project.

when i ran the application getting the error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.

  > Could not resolve org.springframework.vault:spring-vault-core:2.0.1.RELEASE.
  >   Required by:
  >   project : > com.gogoair.ps:xauth-security:2.0.4
  >   Could not resolve org.springframework.vault:spring-vault-core:2.0.1.RELEASE.
  >   Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/springframework/vault/spring-vault-core/2.0.1.RELEASE/spring-vault-core-2.0.1.RELEASE.pom'.
  >   Failed to move file 'C:\Users\CHE32904\AppData\Local\Temp\gradle_download5901172107951949118bin' into filestore at 'D:\softwares\gradle-4.6-bin\gradle-4.6\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.vault\spring-vault-core\2.0.1.RELEASE\562973b9fcc1880af51f50b2d1a53cf8b9f2745c\spring-vault-core-2.0.1.RELEASE.pom' 
  >   Failed to create parent directory 'D:\softwares\gradle-4.6-bin\gradle-4.6\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.vault' when creating directory 'D:\softwares\gradle-4.6-bin\gradle-4.6\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.vault\spring-vault-core\2.0.1.RELEASE\562973b9fcc1880af51f50b2d1a53cf8b9f2745c'